# How Metrics works internally in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, dropwizard

I am working with dropwizard project and used @Timed annotation at resource layer to log our apis it is working fine. I can see logs of that resource in metrics, but my question is "How it resgister our apis with logger and showing detailed logs ?". Please also explain internal working of @Timed annotation if possible.

Comment: It becomes very painful using dropwizard, not getting help any where either on stackover flow or any other platform, due to less documentation availability of drpwizard. So going to migrate my existing project in Spring Boot hoping in that framework will get better help.